# Converting empty list() into NULL in R?

Tags: r, xml, for-loop, if-statement

I am updating a function in R which I did not wrote myself and having trouble working/understanding how to deal with if()

My problem is `xpathApply()`is returning a empty list `list()` and not a `NULL` object, so `if(is.null())` is not returning the `taxon$name`, what causes the next line of code to crash. Is there a way to turn this empty list into a NULL object, or any other solution that can be used with if()? Since I am running this in a for in loop with many iterations and most of the links will not return empty lists.

Here is some reproducible code:

```
library('XML')
library('plyr')
library('httr')


name<- c("Hemigraphis reptans")
URL<- c("https://naturalhistory2.si.edu/botany/marquesasflora/results.cfm?genus=Hemigraphis&specificepithet=reptans&rank=&epithet1=")
taxon<- data.frame(name,URL, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


query_page = htmlTreeParse(rawToChar(GET(taxon$URL)$content), useInternalNodes = T)
  
name_accept = xpathApply(query_page, path = "//*//div[@id = 'mainArticle']//*//b", xmlValue)
  if(is.null(name_accept)){
    return(data.frame(Species = taxon$name))
  }
name_accept = as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(name_accept), ncol = 3, byrow = T), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would no records found be a problem?

Comment: Just changing the `list()` to `NULL` will not help, because you cannot convert it to a matrix (last line). Would be nice to see how it should behave, if the species is accepted. Probably rewrite your code somehow, that you ask `if(length(name_accept) == 0) ...`. The length of an empty list is 0 and the length of `NULL` too.

Comment: @nachti Thanks, that actually worked. I simply changed the ``if(is.null())`` to the suggested ```if(length(name_accept) == 0)```. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if condition from `if(is.null(name_accept))` to `if(length(name_accept) == 0)` may solve the problem. The length of an empty list is 0 and the length of NULL too.